# How to make if statement on product activation?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<form method="get"  formenctype="text/plain"  action="https://app.cryptolens.io/api/key/Activate" >
      <input type="text"   maxlength="23" size="80" name="Key" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" />
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="token" />
      <input type="hidden"   name="ProductId" value="XXXX" />
 </form>
```

so I'm making a desktop app, and it will require users to activate a license key to unlock the software.

I have a form for the user to input the key, which makes a get request to the key api. How do I make it so if the response is valid then it opens the software window, but if its invalid then it throws an exception or error box?

Thanks for your help!

My form is above , and a sample valid response from the api is below.

```html
{"licenseKey":{"productId":XXXX,"id":71,"key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","created":"2019-08-21T01:19:24.223","expires":"2020-02-17T01:19:51.16","period":180,"f1":true,"f2":true,"f3":true,"f4":true,"f5":true,"f6":true,"f7":true,"f8":true,"notes":null,"block":false,"globalId":XXXXX17,"customer":null,"activatedMachines":[{"mid":"","ip":"9XXXXXXX","time":"2019-08-21T01:19:51.16"}],"trialActivation":true,"maxNoOfMachines":1,"allowedMachines":"","dataObjects":[],"signDate":"2019-08-21T19:57:08","signature":null},"result":0,"message":""}
```

I am using Electron.js and Puppeteer

Comment: Could you post some code? What is the api?

Comment: Please mention in which os you are building your application and also which language and stack you are using to build the software.

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee done

Comment: @KarthikSKumar Windows, Electron, Puppeteer, html/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
If(key is correct){
  const messageBoxOptions = {
      type: "question",
      title: "Enter valid key",
      message: "License key is wrong"
  };
  dialog.showMessageBox(messageBoxOptions)
 } else {
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800
    });
   win.loadURL('<url>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik! But how do I read the body of the response, and how do I make it so the screen doesn't show the api response on submit?